# c++ operator overloading library class

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a class from Gtk Library that represents a color(GdkColor)....i have written my own interval tree around it...

Basically, it associates different colors to different intervals...

Now,in my test case, once i do a query for interval,
i want to compare the output with the expected value.

```
typedef struct 
{
   GdkColor color; 

}intervalMetaData;

struct intervalInfo 
{
    signed int low;
    signed int high;
    intervalMetaData _data;

};

metaData = _intervalTree.performQuery(BWInterval);
GdkColor red;
//red==metaData.color //throws an error
```

I cannot overload == for gdkColor since it is from gdk library.

Is there any other way i can get around this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF, and only if, you have all the information you need to determine the equality, it is no problem to define the function yourself:

```
//not sure what GdkColor contains, but if it is large pass by const &
bool operator==(GdkColor a, GdkColor b) {
    //check equality here
    return result;
}
```

`operator==` does not have to be a member function.

If you have no way of comparing two GdkColor instances, you cannot find out if they are equal. Dead simple. If the framework provides no method which allows you to determine equality it probably does so for a good reason. This would usually be something, where neither `<,>,<=, >=, !=, ==` nor anything comparable are provided and access to the members which would define the equality relation is not possible at all. I can't remember wanting to implement an `operator==`, where this was the case. However, if you have to force the API to its limit to implement an equality-comparison, you should investigate why that is so.

The typical case where you would have no access would be a C library, which uses a `typedef` to make a `struct` opaque. However, if it was intended for you to manipulate the contents of the struct or compare them, the framework would provide either something like

`xxx getInformationXXX(struct S)` or a method `int compare(struct S*, struct S*)`

I am not familiar with GdkColor, but I assume, there is some publicly available information that allows you to determine if two instances are equal. You should consider putting this function into a namespace, just in case GdkColor ever implements `operator==` itself to help avoid disambiguation.

Comment: i can get it working this way...but what if i donot know the internals of GdkColor?

Comment: @basav If you don't know the internals, you can't compare it, right? You only can compare their addresses.

Answer (score 0):

1. `operator==` should not be the member of the class (and, probably, does not need an access to private/protected part of it), so it *can* be overloaded.
2. You can create the derived class and overload just anything you want inside it.
3. The simplest thing is just a helper function, kind of `isEqualTo()`, without any overloading at all.

Comment: 1. why shouldn't it be?

2. you can't if the class is final or it will be useless in case its members/methods are private

3. how is that better than standard == operator?